# Record the video played duration in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have app in which i want that when user plays video its time should be save like ali played video for 30 seconds or what ever time.I searched a lot about playBackTime but it did not work for me any other way to get this solved i am using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to play the file here is my code for playing video.

```
    mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [[mp moviePlayer] prepareToPlay];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setUseApplicationAudioSession:NO];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setControlStyle:2];

   [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
```

Comment: Check out my response here
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400342/mpmoviewplayer-calculate-current-time-during-video-play/18406019#18406019][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400342/mpmoviewplayer-calculate-current-time-during-video-play/18406019#18406019

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property **duration**
The duration of the movie, measured in seconds. (read-only)

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSTimeInterval duration
```

Comment: it will tell me the duration of video played or total duration of video

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current playback time like this

```
mp.currentPlaybackTime;
```

You could check this property when the user pauses or stops the video.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement a logic in this way.

when the user starts movie:

```
STARTS TIMER
```

in any case when user pause or get away from that movieplayer probaly you will get a delegate where you get a notification that user stops watching movie:
at that time

```
STOP TIMER
```

this is just logic.

Comment: can you tell delegates for start movie and stop movie

Comment: i got it dear you have to use 

MPMovieAccessLog
:


A movie access log accumulates key metrics about network playback for an associated movie player that is playing.A movie access log describes one uninterrupted period of playback. A movie player (an instance of the MPMoviePlayerController class) can access this log from its setAccessLog: property.

[link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMovieAccessLog_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010561)

Comment: I followed  a link, by this link i got that we are getting worng as  MPMovieAccessLog is usable with only with HSL Vidoes

Comment: We have to stick to the logic dear or may be some one else in minewhile can post    ( positively)